# Using the Continuity Lemma to show that two variables converge.

Tags: probability

Let $X_p$ be Geometric$(p)$ (number of failures). Prove, via characteristic functions and the Continuity Lemma, that $p\cdot X_p$ converges to Exponential$(1)$ in distribution as $p\searrow0$.

I have so far that
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itX_p}\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^kpe^{itk}\\
&=p\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(e^{it}(1-p)\right)^k\\
&=\frac p{1-e^{it}(1-p)}.
\end{align*}
$$
So then $$
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{pitX_p}\right)=\left(\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itX_p}\right)\right)^p=\left(\frac p{1-e^{it}(1-p)}\right)^p.
$$
Let $Y\sim$ Exponential$(1)$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itY}\right)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}e^{itx}\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{x(it-1)}dx\\
&=\frac1{it-1}\left[e^{x(it-1)}\right]_0^\infty\\
&=\frac1{1-it}
\end{align*}
$$
But now my problem comes from showing that
$$
\lim_{p\searrow0}\left(\frac p{1-e^{it}(1-p)}\right)^p=\frac1{1-it}.
$$
In fact, to me this limit looks wrong, which makes me suspicious that some of my earlier workings are incorrect. Could anybody help me calculate this limit, or see where else I might have gone wrong in this question? Any help appreciated!

---

**EDIT** Masacroso pointed out in the comments that I have calculated the charcteristic function of $p\cdot X_p$ incorrectly. So now with the corrections, we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itpX_p}\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p)^kpe^{itpk}\\
&=p\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(e^{itp}(1-p)\right)^k\\
&=\frac p{1-e^{itp}(1-p)}.
\end{align*}
$$
So now I have to show that
$$
\lim_{p\searrow0}\frac p{1-e^{itp}(1-p)}=\frac1{1-it},
$$
which I am still struggling with, but it seems more believable to me than what I had previously calculated. Help with this limit would still be appreciated!

Comment: this step is wrong: $\mathbb{E}\left(e^{pitX_p}\right)=\left(\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itX_p}\right)\right)^p$

Comment: Thanks I have edited the post now. I am still struggling to calculate the limit, do you have any hints for it?

Comment: use L'Hôpital rule to handle the limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use l'Hopital's rule. Let $f(p)=p$, and $g(p)=1-e^{itp}(1-p)$. Then we want to find
$$
\lim_{p\searrow0}\frac{f(p)}{g(p)}=\frac{f'(p)}{g'(p)}
$$
We have that $f'(p)=1$ and $g'(p)=e^{itp}-it(1-p)e^{itp}$. Then
$$
\frac{f'(p)}{g'(p)}=\frac1{1-it}
$$